# Align labels with ridgeline plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, ridgeline-plot

The code below has been prepared to a ridgeline plot for monthly data. Somehow, I am not able to align the month labels with the density plots. See below the code and output. Any advise on how to update the code to do the alignment better?

```py
# Set color pallete
pal = sns.color_palette(palette='coolwarm', n_colors=12)

# Apply sns.FacetGrid class, with the 'hue' argument to represented colors by 'palette'
g = sns.FacetGrid(wind, row='month', hue='mean_month', aspect=15, height=0.75, palette=pal, xlim=(0,100))

# Add the densities kdeplots for each month
g.map(sns.kdeplot, 'Normalized',
      bw_adjust=1, clip=(0,100),
      fill=True, alpha=1, linewidth=1.5)

# Add a horizontal line for each plot
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0,
      lw=2, clip_on=False)

# Loop over the FacetGrid figure axes (g.axes.flat) and add the month as text with the right color
for i, ax in enumerate(g.axes.flat):
    ax.text(-15, 0.02, month_dict[i+1],
            fontweight='bold', fontsize=14,
            color=ax.lines[-1].get_color())

# Use matplotlib.Figure.subplots_adjust() function for subplots to overlap
g.figure.subplots_adjust(hspace=-0.1)

# Remove axes titles, yticks, etc. and add labels
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.set(ylabel=None)
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
plt.xlabel('Wind output [%]', fontweight='bold', fontsize=15)
g.figure.suptitle('Dutch Offshore wind per month (2021-2022)',
                  ha='right',
                  fontsize=20,
                  fontweight=20)

plt.show()
```

Current plot:

[image: current plot]

For another example, the code did nice alignment, but now with a different dataset it is off. Adjusting the `hspace` did not help.

[image: other plot with nice alignment]

Comment: Could you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78126912/edit) an image from your plot? Did your code start from [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html)? Could you also add an image of the plot that went well? Anyway, a ridge plot usually needs quite some manual fine-tuning.

Comment: @JohanC, thanks for your initial reply. I have added the image to the description (forgot the exclamation mark). My code is based on this example: https://python-graph-gallery.com/ridgeline-graph-seaborn/

Comment: It would help if you'd add or link to a similar dataset.  Or create a dummy one with similar values. At least, describe the dataset, e.g. one percentage value per day or per hour or .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ax.text(-15, 0.02, ...)` change the `y=0.02` argument to the average y density value. I think it's too large at the moment, causing the label to be moved far up the y axis. You might first need to delete the line `g.set(yticks=[])` in order to see what the actual y density values are, and then add it back in when you're done.

Alternatively, as per the suggestion below by @JohanC (referencing this [seaborn ridge plot example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html)), you can specify `y=` in axes coordinates as a value between 0 (bottom) and 1 (top). It saves you having to set y based on the data value.

```py
#Place label at left (x=0) and half-way up the y axis (y=0.5)
ax.text(x=0, y=0.5, transform=ax.transAxes, s=<text string>, ...)
```

Comment: It could help to use the approach of the [original source](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html), with `ax.text(..., transform=ax.transAxes)` and use [axes coordinates](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/artists/transforms_tutorial.html) to position the text.

Comment: I think that's a neater solution, as it saves the user from having to adjust the label for new data. I've updated the answer with your suggestion.